# Use custom colors with Spreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, ruby-on-rails-4, spreadsheet-gem

I need to use custom `color` and `pattern_fg_color` (*HEX*: 0x00adb1, *RGB*: 0,173,177). I was following advice from [here](http://andisxp.blogspot.ru/2011/12/export-to-excel-with-spreadsheet-gem.html), but it didn't work out for me (I am using it in another library based on the Spreadsheet gem):

```
Spreadsheet::Excel::Internals::SEDOC_ROLOC.update(enterprise: 0x00adb1)
Spreadsheet::Column.singleton_class::COLORS << :enterprise
```

Test example:

```
Spreadsheet::Format.new(pattern_fg_color: :enterprise)
```

And I get the following error:

> unknown color 'enterprise'

Any suggestions would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that mapping an existing color to another hex/rgb code is much easier than adding a new one, so my solution implies that a built-in `:xls_color_41` is changed.

#### Second approach

Actually, I've achieved the same result without monkey patching, using gem's native method `Spreadsheet::Workbook#set_custom_color`:

```
document = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
document.set_custom_color(41, 0x00, 0xad, 0xb1)
```

#### First approach:

I've ended up with monkey patching `Spreadsheet::Excel::Writer::Workbook` class: instead of default Excel '97 palette that was returned by `default_palette` method, I've defined a method, that changes returned palette for `:xls_color_41`  from `[0x33, 0xcc, 0xcc]` to `[0x00, 0xad, 0xb1]`. The result is as follows:

```
module Spreadsheet
  module Excel
    module Writer
      class Workbook  < Spreadsheet::Writer

        alias_method :excel_palette, :default_palette

        def palette_modifier
          {
            41 => [0x00, 0xad, 0xb1]
          }
        end

       def default_palette
         excel_palette.map.with_index{|rgb, code| [code, rgb]}.to_h.update( palette_modifier ).values
       end

      end
    end
  end
end
```